# How to evaluate the interaction between 3 factors with a single observation in each cell?

Tags: r, anova, experiment-design, factor-analysis

**Some context:** An experiment was conducted to evaluate the interaction between 3 factors in the removal of a contaminant from water. The selected factors were:

1. Coagulant: a chemical substance to improve the removal
2. Velocity: the velocity of mixing the coagulant and water
3. Solids: amount of solids in the water

The experiment results were (data frame constructed in R):

```
Coagulant <- c(rep("Chem_1", times = 9),
               rep("Chem_2", times = 9))

Velocity <- rep(c(rep("low", times = 3),
              rep("mid", times = 3),
              rep("high", times = 3)),
              times = 2)

Solids <- rep(c(0,50,100), times = 6)

Removal <- c(90.60, 77.35, 55.72, 91.96, 63.99, 33.86,
90.03, 51.42, 21.52, 85.28, 80.86, 2.83,
85.73, 64.33, 10.31, 85.05, 46.32, 15.63)


Ex.data.frame <- data.frame(Coagulant,
                            Velocity,
                            Solids, 
                            Removal)

Ex.data.frame$Coagulant <- factor(Ex.data.frame$Coagulant,
                                    levels = c("Chem_1", "Chem_2"),
                                    labels = c("Chem_1", "Chem_2"))

Ex.data.frame$Velocity <- factor(Ex.data.frame$Velocity,
                             levels = c("low", "mid", "high"),
                             labels = c("low", "mid", "high"))

Ex.data.frame$Solids <- factor(Ex.data.frame$Solids,
                                  levels = c(0, 50, 100),
                                  labels = c(0, 50, 100))
```

[image]

I thought about doing a three-way ANOVA, however I have only one measure for each group.

Is there any way that allows me to analyze this data similarly to how ANOVA does?

Comment: What is preventing you from running an ANOVA?  Also, I'd suggest treating Solids as a continuous variable rather than categorical, unless you have a specific reason to not do so. You could get the 2-way interactions via:  lm(Removal ~ Solids * Coagulant + Solids * Velocity + Coagulant * Velocity, data = Ex.data.frame).  The emmeans and sjPlot packages, especially sjPlot::plot_model, might be helpful to you. I've also read afex is good, though I haven't used it yet, myself.